# Unable to remove a specific Item from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array as

```
arr=[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"ram","value":"2"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]
```

I need to remove the first index from this array and it should be of below type

```
[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]
```

I tried splice as below

```
arr.splice(1,1)
```

But it is giving response `{"name":"ram","value":"2"}`

how to get `[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]`

It might be very simple question but Im stuck here from sometime.can someone plz help

Comment: After using `arr.splice(1,1)` you can log `arr` and it should return those values for you...

Comment: Try using `arr.shift()` to remove the first element. Otherwise, use `splice(index, 1)`.

Comment: See here: https://code-boxx.com/remove-elements-javascript-array

Answer (score 3):

I think you taking the returning value of [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array containing the deleted elements.

> The [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place

```js
arr=[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"ram","value":"2"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]

arr.splice(1,1)

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You remove the second index that is 1. The first index is 0 as the question ask to do. So, should be arr.splice(0,1)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the difference methods. Be aware if you need change the array or just get a copy to keep with the original one.

> **Attention**: The first array index is `0`, not `1`. The index one is the second element of the array

> The splice method return the element removed from array. That's the reason why you've got the second element from array in your test

Doc: https://bytearcher.com/articles/how-to-delete-value-from-array/

In your question you got the second index that is `1`, in order to get the values that was shown, I'll use the index `1` as well.

```js
//DELETE
arr=[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"ram","value":"2"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]
delete arr[1];
console.log("using delete",arr)

//SPLICE METHOD
arr=[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"ram","value":"2"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]
let firstElement = arr.splice(1,1)
console.log("using splice",arr)
console.log("the method splice return the element removed from array",firstElement )

//FILTER METHOD
arr=[{"name":"sam","value":"1"},{"name":"ram","value":"2"},{"name":"jam","value":"3"},{"name":"dam","value":"4"}]
let copyArr = arr.filter((element, index)=>index !== 1)
console.log("extra: using filter (will return a array copy)",copyArr)
```